# Spring Kafka replay old messages

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have requirement to replay old Kafka offsets incase of any issue. Is there any API available in spring Kafka to replay old offset of a topic?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Have a look at [ConsumerSeekAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerSeekAware.html). The usage is described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#seek). Namely, about this method:

```
void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback);
```

in the docs is written:

> called when the container is started; this callback should be used
>   when seeking at some arbitrary time after initialization. You should
>   save a reference to the callback; if you are using the same listener
>   in multiple containers (or in a ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer)
>   you should store the callback in a ThreadLocal or some other structure
>   keyed by the listener Thread.

The callback itself is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerSeekAware.ConsumerSeekCallback.html).

Comment: Also, in newer versions (since 2.0), you can use a `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListrener` to perform seeks on the `Consumer` when partitions are assigned.

Comment: Thanks Lachezar. Thanks Gary.

Comment: I tried implementing consumerSeekAware and registering consumerseekcallback using threadlocal. It works within the listener class But I want to call seek method from other class like triggering from REST API. I would like to set offset of a topic and partition using some REST API so that I will have control to replay old offset whenever it is required. Any help on how I can achieve this?